# Crystal report RAS integration with J2EE web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, crystal-reports, websphere, integration, report

All,
as I understand it, there are 2 ways of integrating crystal reports in to J2EE application.

one is using RAS and other is JRC.

JRC is 100% java integration.

What I want to know is if I take the RAS approach, can I use it in a j2ee application that is supposed to go on a Websphere app server 7.0 app server on a AIX box?

Meaning can RAS report integration approach be OS independent like JRC?
Any advantage or disadvantage be great.. with some example/guide link. I already referred this:

http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/devlib.htm#en/JRC_SDK/jrc_java_dg_doc/doc/jrcsdk_java_dg/WorkingWithJRC2.html#1000972

and

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0717_bajaj/

I believe they talk about JRC, anything on RAS please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the RAS SDK under WebSphere 6.1 on AIX, so it does work. Regrettably, I can't give you more detail than that.

In that same library in your first link, see the Report Application Server SDK, Developer Guides and API Reference, Java Developer Guide.